# DIVs inside a DIV are misplaced when resizing browser window

Tags: html, css, image, resize, image-resizing

I have a web page where i have a parent DIV and then multiple child DIVs inside.
Parent DIV has background image and i made it resizable but the problem is that when i resize webpage all child DIVs are misplaced.

Is there any way to fix that?

[image: Full size browser]
[image: Smaller size browser]

HTML

```
<div class="boiler_room">
    <div class="HVAC_PUMP_01_STS">ON</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.boiler_room {
    position: absolute;
    background-image:url('boiler_room_schema.jpeg');
    background-size: contain;
    object-fit: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.HVAC_PUMP_01_STS {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 305px;
    left: 960px;
}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error using code, you've provided in question.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/b5uphwf8/1/

Comment: Still it does not indicates problem. It seems that most of your problem depends on resizing algorithm. Using percentage value from the fiddle you've provided in comment simply changes position of "ON".
Probably you should use javascript to adapt div's position accordingly to your resizing algorithm.

Comment: Problem is that parent div is set to 100% in height and width and as far as i see the child div positions are fine when i use % for top and right parameters.

Problem is that because parent div is set to 100% it is bigger than the image

Comment: That's also too few information. What is size of parent element of `.boiler_room`. Is it constant or it depends (you've got height: 100%)?

Comment: @JanKeber Just to clarify, you do really need the picture to become narrower than the window? You can't just keep the picture the width of the window and provide a vertical scrollbar?

Comment: This is the entire code. .boiler_room does not have a parent

Comment: I need the picture to resize for different screen resolutions, phones etc.

Comment: @JanKeber That wasn't what I asked.